# How to create public_html folder?

Tags: apache, httpserver

I accidentally deleted my "Public_html" folder from the web server. After accessing by fileZilla  agent there is no public_html folder present. How can i upload the files to the web server  and how can i create it again ?

Comment: Erm, create a new public_html directory with Filezilla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In FileZilla, right-click in the remote pane and select Create Directory. Name it 'public_html'.

Secondly, drag your files from the local panel on the local pane to the remote pane to upload files to your public_html folder.

Comment: M it would not have any read authority ..
it may be considered as root directory by their host ...

Answer (score 2):

You should access via ssh to the server in order to have access to the console command. From there if your server is linux:

```
mkdir ~/public_html
fs sa ~/public_html system:anyuser read
```

or else, if your server is IIS:

```
cd /home/[yourUser]/domains/domain
mkdir public_html
chown [yourUser]:[yourUser] public_html
chmod 755 public_html
```

replace [yourUser] with your user name.

Hope this helps.